# D3: how to disable zoom on icons with background image?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to position icons on a D3 map. These icons I build by inserting shapes and filling their background with a picture (PNG, SVG, etc.)

This works fine until you try to zoom. When you zoom in, the icons get distorted with the transform, and I am unable to keep them fixed / consistent with the size of the parent shape. Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/Lo2mjhjq/3/

How do I amend the zoom so that it does not mess with the avatar icon? Pseudo code should be:

```
d3.select("#avatar").attr("transform", "scale(*don't scale with rest*)
 translate(*translate with rest to enable panning*)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution (out of many) is applying the same change to the `<image>` element:

```
d3.select("#avatar")
    .select("image")
    .attr("width", 40 / d3.event.scale)
    .attr("height", 40 / d3.event.scale);
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nm8bLLcL/